# Shortest distance to visit all nodes for an undirected weighted graph

Tags: shortest-path

Given an undirected weighted graph with N nodes. The distance between any two nodes is given by the edge weight. Node 1 is the source and node N is the destination. The task is to visit all the nodes with minimum distance travelled.

Comment: Have you tried anything before posting your question? If yes, then please show some code !

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find anything help me with this problem!.